# Turning back from update on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is any code from backing from update on SQL Server. I mean without triggers and logs.

KR,

Çağın

Comment: That question is not worded very well. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Needs more detail. What are you trying to do? You can `rollback` the transaction instead of committing it - this obviously uses the transaction log.

Comment: Are you talking about rolling back your changes?

Comment: Voted to close. Belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: I mean, if it is possible take back the old datas after update statement.

Comment: Still don't really know what you're asking. Are you talking about recovering from a mistake?

Comment: @Martin: Yes i m talking about recovering from a mistake.

Comment: You can't recover from this once it is committed without the transaction logs then. Do you definitely not have these? What does the following query return? `SELECT name,recovery_model_desc, CASE WHEN last_log_backup_lsn IS NULL THEN 'On' ELSE 'Off' END as AutoTruncate FROM sys.databases d join sys.database_recovery_status r ON r.database_id=d.database_id`

Comment: it is returning FULL for recovery_model_desc and OFF for AutoTruncate for my data base

Comment: In that case it ought to be possible for you (or possibly your DBA?) to do a point in time recovery into a new database using the last backup and the transaction logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to have change data capture or audit logging, you can easily recover from a bad change. Or as suggested you can restore yesterday's backup to another instance and then copy the data as much as possible. If you don't have any of these things, perhaps you need to them set up for future problems. Or maybe even hire a database professional so you don't get caught like this again. And of course,  take all update, delete and insert rights away from application ddevelopers on production. Sometimes the best thing you can do is at least learn from your mistakes and make the system better for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's rather just "update was wrong" and now finding out there is no Undo like in Word.

Depends on what has been done else to the data. You could restore the effected columns by restoring your yesterday's backup of the database to another database, different name (don't overwrite your current database ...), and set up an update query to restore just your columns. Referencing tables in other databases is basically a simple syntax like database.schema.table; you have to look up the details on msdn, haven't had the need to do that before.

Alternatively, use a frontend dbms, e.g. Access, link both old and new table and name them in a way easy to distinguish between them, and set up an update query in Access to restore the old values. Might be that you need to cache your old values in a local table in your dbms.

If your answer is, you don't have a backup, then you are really lost.